# How to get average accuracy in multivariate model?

Tags: python, keras, regression, conv-neural-network, multivalue

I have modeled multivariate model with more than 100 different output layers in parallel.
I am able to get averaged loss function, but it is not really possible for me to get averaged accuracy values. (I am doing regression)
Would you be kind enough as to suggest any idea of how to do this in KERAS?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: do you want to make an average of the metrics? for example, make the average of rmse of all the outputs?

Comment: Yes I want! Could you guide me?

Comment: I added an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a custom callback to do this

```
class MergeMetrics(Callback):

    def __init__(self,**kargs):
        super(MergeMetrics,self).__init__(**kargs)

    def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        logs['merge_mse'] = np.mean([logs[m] for m in logs.keys() if 'mse' in m])
        logs['merge_mae'] = np.mean([logs[m] for m in logs.keys() if 'mae' in m])
```

I use this callback to merge 2 metrics coming from 2 different outputs. I use a simple problem for example but you can integrate it easily in your problem and integrate it with a validation set

this is the dummy example where I use mse and mae as metrics

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)
y2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)

inp = Input((10,))
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp)
out1 = Dense(1, name='y1')(x)
out2 = Dense(1, name='y2')(x)
m = Model(inp, [out1,out2])
m.compile('adam','mae', metrics=['mse','mae'])

checkpoint = MergeMetrics()
m.fit(X, [y1,y2], epochs=10, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

the printed output is:

```
loss: ... - y1_mse: 0.2227 - y1_mae: 0.3884 - y2_mse: 0.1163 - y2_mae: 0.2805 - merge_mse: 0.1695 - merge_mae: 0.3345
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support!, but Callback in class is not recognized. Do I need to import something to use?

Comment: it's tf.keras.callbacks.Callback ... don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much!